# Employer biased community members skewing the intent of the site

Tags: discussion, support

Recently I am trying to be as active as possible in the community and coincidently I joined a new job so I am up with lots of questions which I feel are important from my point of view.

I know that its an open community and everyone's opinion is equally welcomed but I see that there are few members who hold many badges but their answers/comments solves no purpose other than either praising employers or simply neglecting every point made by OP.

Some examples:

1. You are given salary so just do it.
2. You are employee this will happen.
3. etc.

These kind of comments and answer met the OP down and simply nullifies the intent of this site.

I am concerned about the quality of the discussion because these members hold most of the power to play with questions and often good questions dies or are put on hold.

Adding more references:

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/85254/60598

Now, who says one doesn't have free time in office? we are paid to do the work and not complete the 8 hour slot just sitting there and looking at wall. if someone is good in their trade then they can finish the work at hand and use the time left for personal training, the answer again here is employer biased, it masked few category of the people happy.

Comment: Just curious - what do you think is "the intent of this site"? (I understand you didn't like my answer to https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/97904/salary-got-delayed-in-the-new-job , but I don't understand what is "skewed" here. Others are always free to weigh in with a different answer.)

Comment: @JoeStrazzere since we are on it, its very clear that being one of the top rated member people would read your answer first, and as we discussed I don't feel your answers are un biased.

Comment: No worries. Since it bothered you so much, I deleted my answer. I was trying to give you an honest answer, but apparently you are looking for something else. Good luck. I still have no idea what you perceive regarding "the intent of the site" but I suspect we disagree on that.

Comment: Not everyone is employer-biased: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/7318/437

Comment: I don't really understand what your objection is here, specific examples would help a lot.

Comment: Since it has been requested not only once, could you explain what do you think about "*the intent of this site*"?

Comment: @enderland I could have given concrete example but someone just deleted his answer, what to expect?

Comment: There are members, such as @JoeStrazzere ( and others ) who have helped many people over a long period of time and have *earned* their stripes.  The **beauty** of this site is one member cannot kill a question.  The community votes on questions, answers , and allows members to FLAG comments they feel are inappropriate.  One of the hardest ( at least for me ) lessons to learn about this site is that not everyone agrees with my view of things.  And you know what, its actually ok.  The community as a whole decides ( along with your own personal view ) what is and isn't good content.

Comment: I assure you that the vast majority of folks with decent rep are here to help, and are not skewed toward the employer or the employee.

Comment: @johndoe - as I indicated, I deleted my answer since it apparently wasn't what you were looking for and seemed to upset you somehow. As far as I can tell, it fit in perfectly well with *the intent of this site*. The hope was that someone else could figure out what you wanted and provide such an answer. Since then you have removed everything but one sentence of your question, significantly changing the meaning and it has been put on hold as being "off topic". Good luck.

Comment: @johndoe If you've discovered an actual pattern of "employer bias" then surely you could point to *several* examples? Because the [now-deleted answer that Joe posted](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/97926/25739) certainly doesn't qualify as an example of bias. Frankly, I get the impression that you're here simply to harangue Joe because you disagree with his answer. I think you have some fundamental misconceptions on the employer-employee dynamic and rather than consider that you might be wrong you seem to prefer calling the people who take the time to explain corporate shills.

Comment: @Lilienthal why I would make a sole motive to do so? do you really want me to spend time and make several references then I will do it for sure and let me remind you no person here I given them so much value to take personal grudges with him. I am not surprised by the wording used here many of the community members it was expected and gives me feeling that I am thinking in the right sense. Do you know he edited answer before deleting the post?

Comment: @MisterPositive I also think same and that's why I am here.

Comment: @johndoe Well, I don't really "want" you to spend time on that. You're the one raising the issue which means that the burden of proof is on you so if *you* want to discuss this you'll *have* to come up with some examples. Simply put, I think you're confusing "employer bias" with "being professional". In an employer-employee relationship both sides have rights and obligations. The two examples you've given so far are clear cases where the OP hasn't realized that what he's asking is across that boundary. Work time is not study time. An employer is not responsible for your personal finances.

Comment: @Lilienthal so you are saying that employer is not responsible for paying salary on time?

Comment: @johndoe Well, that's what you perceive to be the problem here, but I think virtually everyone else disagrees that that's the real issue in your situation.It seems like you failed to plan adequately for a job switch, assumed that you'd be paid on Date X without checking with your new employer and now blame them instead of your own inability to carry expenses for more than a month or plan adequately. The crux of Joe's answer was that this is outside the employer's responsibility but that you *could* ask them for some kind of arrangement although that's a bad idea for a few reasons.

Answer (score 9):

Here is the complete content of my now-deleted answer. Perhaps you could indicate what was objectionable so that others can provide an answer more to your liking. Note that you have radically changed your question since then, and that I provided the answer in response to the original question.

---

> > Why such a policy exists where the bonus is given in the month end
> >     when it is needed upfront? I could have saved all the expenses in the
> >     hotels.
>
> For the answer to "why" you'll have to ask the company (perhaps HR). Many companies don't like to give money up front since some people accept the up-front bonus then never show up. It's expensive to chase after them to get the money back. Perhaps your company thinks this way too.
>
> It seems as if the crux of your troubles revolves around when payroll is credited each month. You were expecting the end of the month, but in reality they credit accounts on the 20th of each month. It's unfortunate you didn't ask these questions up front so that you could have planned better. I doubt that the company was hiding anything here.
>
> > What if the HR says that the payroll is out and now you will get all
> >     the salary in the next payroll and who is responsible for the next
> >     week of accommodations which is going to cost me like anything?
>
> Unfortunately, you are responsible for your own accommodations and expenses.
>
> I suppose you could talk with HR and see if they could make an exception and help you out with an advance, but in my experience it would be unlikely. It's worth trying anyway.

Comment: This is a solid truthful and useful answer, I would not waste anymore energy on this if I were you sir.

Comment: @MisterPositive - Thanks. I don't view it as a waste if it helps the OP's understanding, and perhaps attracts an answer to the original question that is useful to someone.

Comment: @MisterPositive for your and other's kind information the word "Unfortunately, " was added just before deleting the answer. The real sentence was "you are responsible for your own accommodations and expenses."

Comment: @johndoe Not sure why that matters.  The end result is the same, you are responsible for your own accommodations and expenses.

Comment: @MisterPositive not if the employer delays the salary.

Comment: It doesn't appear that the employer did that. And, for example, if I don't pay my electric bill, and they shut off my electricity, the electric company doesn't care.  I am responsible for my accommodations and expenses **ultimately**.

Comment: @johndoe - I did indeed add the word "unfortunately" during my last edit of the answer. In the interest of full disclosure I also added "It seems as if the crux of your troubles revolves around when payroll is credited each month. You were expecting the end of the month, but in reality they credit accounts on the 20th of each month." and "I doubt that the company was hiding anything here." I don't see what that has to do with anything, but hopefully this helps. I deleted the answer when it became clear that you were looking for something else. Good luck.

Comment: @MisterPositive either I am failing to explain my situation or you don't want to understand. The mistake of employer was to let me know the rules and regulations of the salary like other things after joining, if others get their salary by 20th and today is what? and I still don't have salary in my account then its my mistake? its my first month after joining and I am managing my expenses since one month and never uttered a word.

Comment: @johndoe "either I am failing to explain my situation or..." Yes, that one. You are really being very unclear about your situation. It sounds like you expected a deposit in your account but didn't get it because you didn't provide them your account info in time. It's *extremely* common for the first paycheck to be a physical check and not direct deposit. Have you received a check in the mail? Do you need to stop by payroll to pick it up? They can't just not pay you because they don't have your bank info - you have a check waiting for you somewhere.

Comment: @johndoe I think your *situation* is clear, but your *goal* is not clear. This was also one of the close reasons on your question, I hope you read the explanation there. So, you couldn't open your bank account in time to give the account number to your employer. As a result, you haven't received your salary, so you cannot go searching for a more permanent accomodation. You are spending a lot of money on your temporary accomodation. Now, what exactly do you want us to help you with?

Comment: @DavidK It's actually exceptionally rare in the UK, especially for more "professional" jobs.

Comment: @motosubatsu Just trying to understand - you're saying it's rare to not have the first paycheck on direct deposit? How do employer's handle a situation like this, where the employee didn't provide account info soon enough for the first paycheck?

Comment: @DavidK yep - I appreciate it's not the *biggest* sample in a statistical sense but other than casual "cash-in-hand" stuff I've only been paid outside of direct deposit *once* in my entire career and that was when the payroll person screwed up and the directors had to go get cash for everyone! In situations like this the employer usually does exactly what the OP's employer has done and rolled it into the next payment run. In the event of financial hardship they *might* give an advance but that's entirely at their discretion.

Comment: @motosubatsu Honestly, the OP 's main issue here is not the delayed payment, but his attitude in dealing with unforeseen problems. If he had focussed on how to get his salary, rather than how to blame the employer, he might have been more open to try the suggestion of politely requesting for a salary advance. This is going to be problematic for him going forward because when you move your base to a foreign country, you have to be as broad-minded as possible, *especially* when you are going to a different culture, as in this case (OP is from India, now moved to UK).

Comment: @MaskedMan couldn't agree more.. just got myself a little sidetracked there!

Comment: @motosubatsu Oh, I wasn't complaining or anything. Uhm, actually I don't even know why I am participating in this discussion. 